# -webkit-calc function does not work in firefox. Is there any alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a logo with `68px` width and I wanted to show this logo right in the top-center of the page. So I put it in the nav-bar and I give this style to it:

```css
.center{
  position: absolute;
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 34px);
  right: -webkit-calc(50% - 34px);
  img{
    margin: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

At the first I used `left: 50%` and `right: 50%`, but there was a problem: the size of logo was not count, so it doesn't show up in the center (exactly center!) So I used `-webkit-calc(50% - 34px);` to calculate the size of logo. The problem is that it works in Chrome but it's not working in Firefox!

It's what firefox shows in `inspect element`:
[image]

Is there any alternative for this function for firefox?

Comment: use fallback without `-webkit-`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: also no -webkit- prefix needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `calc`:

```css
.center{
  position: absolute;
  left:  calc(50% - 34px);
  right: calc(50% - 34px);
  img{
    margin: 11px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
}
```

`-webkit-` is the prefix used by Safari and Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Brave, the new Microsoft Edge). (`-moz-` is the one used by Firefox [for "Mozilla"]; IE and Legacy Edge used `-ms-`) But `calc` hasn't needed prefixing for a while now.